# How to normalize this table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, normalization

Hi this is my Unnormalized table

```
BookOrNo  PublisherCode  PublisherName  PublisherAddr PubishedDate  ISBNno Desc     Qty  Price 
B001      P120           A              …….          3/2/11        01-9   Fiction   3   20.00 
                                                                   01-10  Fashion   6   25.00
B002      P121           B              …….          3/2/11        01-11  sports    15  30.00
```

I tried to normalized but i failed. This is my normalized steps

```
BookOrder (BookOrNo,PublisherCode,ISBNno,Qty)
Book (ISBNno,Desc,Price,PublishedDate)
Publisher(PublisherCode,PublisherName,PublisherAddr)
```

normalized STEPS to 1NF, 2NF, 3NF.

Comment: This is homework?  You should state that.  (or if not say so).  Here's something to ask yourself: When you order a few books from Amazon, what would they put for the the publisher for that book order?

Comment: "I failed" - How do you know?

Comment: You got Book and Publisher up to 3NF (assuming ISBNno is your primary key in Book). BookOrder needs work. Do you need PublisherCode having the ISBNNo already? What about the price? It is in Book, but this will eventually change. The Order must stay static, so you'll need price there as well. You're on the right track.

Comment: What about BCNF and 5NF?

Comment: @onedaywhen: and 4NF? (not the same as BCNF)

Comment: @MarkBannister: when was the last time you saw a relvar in 4NF that wasn't also in 5NF in the wild (i.e. other than for pedagogic purposes)? 2NF and 3NF aren't very useful either.

Comment: @onedaywhen: "2NF and 3NF aren't very useful either." - Seriously?

Comment: @MarkBannister: 5NF is the de facto standard in theory and in practice. 5NF is always achievable and is the minimum requirement for a 'fully normalized' relvar; anything less is denormalized. Codd messed up the definition of 3NF and corrected it with BCNF. 2NF is merely a stepping stone to BCNF, which itself is just a stepping stone to 5NF. 6NF is nice to know in theory but is not always useful in practice...

Comment: ...Most designers use common sense and experience, rather than applying the formal normalization process, and most of the time they either achieve 5NF or fail to meet 1NF (duplicate rows, non-scalar values, nulls, etc). In my experience, a code review should identify a deisgn that is not fully normalized but participants never spend time worrying about whether it meets 2NF, 3NF, 4NF, etc and the designer probably wouldn't care if you told them anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone thanks for the explanations. After 2days I solve this question.

@Levin Magruder yes this is my homework

@onedaywhen. yes your are absolutely correct. I can convert directly to normalized table into normalized. But I cant go through step by step. But now i thank i can. :).

This is my answer. Hope this will help to someone.

[image: Solved Normalization]